# Undefined method 'criteria' for Ruby Object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

```
undefined method `criteria' for #<Timeclock:0x00000106a969b8>
```

MongoMapper - MongoDB - tried to define the following scope in the Timeclock class:

```
  scope :last_clock_time, ->(session) do
    where({:user => session[:user_id]}).sort(:created_at.desc).first() 
  end
```

I call `Timeclock.last_clock_time(session)` and I get the error at the top.

Not even sure what 'criteria' is in this case

EDIT :

So I post a question and then go play around with it - I changed this:

```
scope :last_clock_time, ->(session) do
        where({:user => session[:user_id]}).sort(:created_at.desc)
      end
```

And then I call `Timeclock.last_clock_time.first()` and it works

Why?

Comment: Can you show the full `Timeclock` class ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit The rest of the class doesn't matter here. What are scopes supposed to return?

Comment: @muistooshort As far as I know *scopes* should return `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Comment: @ArupRakshit A scope should return whatever thing are used to represent queries. In ActiveRecord that would be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, in Mongoid it would be a `Mongoid::Criteria`, in MongoMapper it would be something else.

Comment: @muistooshort Humm That's why I jumped into the `Mongoid::Criteria` doc. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `last_clock_time` is not really a scope at all, it is just a query that returns **at most one `Timeclock`**. A scope is supposed to return a query (AKA "criteria" or "search criteria") so that you can chain it:

```
Model.scope1.scope2.where(...)...
```

When you call `first` on the query, you get a `Timeclock` instance (or `nil` of course) and model instances don't have `criteria` methods, queries and model classes do have a `criteria` method and that's the sort of thing that a scope is supposed to return.

Somewhere something is assuming that your scope really is a scope and calling `criteria` on its return value to work with the underlying query. But your scope is a lie because it returns that wrong sort of thing.

When you drop the `first` call, your scope stops being a lie and returns what a scope is supposed to return. Once your scope stops lying, everything starts to work.

Comment: Humm I am trying to match it with the doc - http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html. Thus asked OP to show the full class. I am not much expert in Rails, so without confirming I am not able to help others,  :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit Why read Mongoid docs to learn about MongoMapper? Also note that the `criteria` method seems to have been renamed in newer versions of MongoMapper.

Comment: Why are you telling *Your original last_clock_time is not really a scope at all* - As far as I learned till now it is called as *named scope*, or basically it is a *class method*.. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: *named scopes* and *scopes* are the same thing, they're both fancy ways of creating class methods (in fact, scopes that take arguments are [supposed to be written as simple class methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)). Something that doesn't return a query isn't really a scope even if you use `scope` to create the class method.

Comment: @ArupRakshit You can say `scope :haha, ->{ 6 }` but it still doesn't define a scope even though it uses the `scope` method to create the underlying  `self.haha` class method.

Comment: Last question - From inside of `scope`, if we try to return a `Active::Record` object, then Rails will prevent us in doing so by *error*, this way it is written right ? It is true always.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: This is about MongoMapper, not ActiveRecord. You shouldn't expect their behaviors to be the same, especially when you abuse them by not conforming to the expected return value.

Comment: @Mu - I appreciate the explanation.  I take a bit of offense to the term "abuse" - if I knew what the expected value was, I wouldn't have had the question in the first place :)

Comment: @notaceo I meant no offence, perhaps *accidental abuse* or *mistaken return value* would be better :)